# Why users doesn't adding to the database? (PHP, PDO, OOP)

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I am new to PHP OOP, so I have problem here. I've searched a lot, but couldn't find any useful information. I am trying to add the users to the database and my code doesn't adding any users to it and it doesn't print any error result. Could someone help me to solve this problem? Where am I doing a mistake? Thank you for any help!

Here is my database.php file:

```
class Database
{
    private $host = 'DB_HOST';
    private $user = 'DB_USER';
    private $password = 'DB_PASSWORD';
    private $dbName = 'DB_NAME';
    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;
    private $name;
    private $lastname;
    private $employmentDate;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Setting Database Source Name (DSN)
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName;
        // Setting options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        // Making the connection to the database
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->password, $options);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // Avoiding SQL injection with prepare statement
    public function query($query)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    // Binding the values
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = NULL)
    {
        if(is_null($type)) {
            switch(TRUE) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    // Executing the prepared statement
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function insertUserValues()
    {
        $database->query('INSERT INTO employee (name,surname,employment_date)
         VALUES (:name, :surname, :employmentDate)');
    }

    public function bindingTheValues()
    {
        $database->bind(':name', $this->name = $_POST['name']);
        $database->bind(':lastname', $this->lastname = $_POST['lastname']);
        $database->bind(':employmentDate', $this->employmentDate = $_POST['employmentDate']);
        $database->execute();
    }
}

// Instantiate database
$database = new Database();
?>
```

I know that my code is quite long, but I am just trying to insert all the stuff that I've been written.

And here is my entryform.php file:

```
<?php
// Include database class
include 'database.php';
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_NAME", "employees");
?>
```

Thank you for any help...

Comment: Can you let us know the error your are receiving? It will help us determine the problem

Comment: I do not receive any errors, it's just doesn't adding any users to the database... I think i did something wrong with the $database->bind(':name',$this->name = $_POST['name']);

Comment: You show where you instantiate the database, but you don't show how you're using it.

Comment: Can you make sure your post values are passing through, let us know whats comes through, go through it all step by step you will see whats missing from the array.

Comment: You should replace `$database->query` with `$database->exec`

Comment: If you're using the bindingTheValues function, you're doing it wrong. Don't assign the variables inside of the bind function. All you're doing there is passing the `true (1)` value into the database.

Comment: Could you tell me how that function should look like or I should just delete it? But if I will delete it, where I need to assign those values?

Comment: @HELPME you went all the way and mess up the code that I showed you in your previous question

Comment: he messed the answer from here that he marked as correct @HELPME http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551050/how-to-write-prepare-and-execute-statements-in-oop-pdo/42554795#42554795

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write prepare and execute statements in OOP PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551050/how-to-write-prepare-and-execute-statements-in-oop-pdo)

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I appreciate your faithful trust in my article, but please read the answer below. the code you wrote based on culttt article is unacceptable.

Comment: What's certainly doesn't work for you in the answer I wrote?

Answer (score -2):

[aynber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557587/why-users-doesnt-adding-to-the-database-php-pdo-oop#comment72249779_42557587) is right. 
You only initialize the `Database` instance. It will only call `__construct` method.

You need to call methods you want to execute after it.
For example:

```
$database = new Database();
$database->insertUserValues();
```

**However**, this will only give you errors, which you can debug on you own way.

Or you can try following which should work:

```
<?php
class Database
{
   private $host = 'DB_HOST';
    private $user = 'DB_USER';
    private $password = 'DB_PASSWORD';
    private $dbName = 'DB_NAME';
    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;
    private $name;
    private $lastname;
    private $employmentDate;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Setting Database Source Name (DSN)
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName;
        // Setting options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        // Making the connection to the database
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->password, $options);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // Avoiding SQL injection with prepare statement
    public function query($query)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    // Binding the values
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = NULL)
    {
        if(is_null($type)) {
            switch(TRUE) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    // Executing the prepared statement
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }
}


$database = new Database();
// prep
$database->query('INSERT INTO employee (name,surname,employment_date)
 VALUES (:name, :surname, :employmentDate)');

 // bind
$database->bind(':name', $_POST['name']);
$database->bind(':lastname', $_POST['lastname']);
$database->bind(':employmentDate', $_POST['employmentDate']);

// execute
$database->execute();
```

Comment: You still have an issue in the binding. You need to remove the variable assignment.

Answer (score -2):

you have few errors

1. you include database before defining constants
2. in database code constants must be without quotes

Answer (score -2):

This code you blindly copy-pasted from someone else's answer makes absolutely no sense. Whole code I mean, not just some trifle part of it. There is an article of mine which explains in detail, why this code is terrible, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Though I suppose you aren't much interested in reading, so here goes the code

```
<?php
class employee
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $lastname;
    public $employmentDate;

    public function __construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->dbh = $pdo;
    }
    public function insertUserValues()
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO employee (name,surname,employment_date) VALUES (?,?,?)';
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$this->name,$this->surname,$this->employmentDate]);
        $this->id = $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }
}

// Instantiate PDO
$dsn = "mysql:host=DB_HOST;dbname=DB_NAME;"
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASSWORD', $options);

// Instantiate emploee
$employee = new employee($pdo);

// assign values
$employee->name = "OMG";
$employee->surname = "Stack Overflow is a terrible place";
$employee->employmentDate = "Teaching you awful code";

// run your insert
$employee->insertUserValues();
```

The main idea here is that your application class should be separated from database class. and that you don't need a database class for a while as PDO is a good one already

Comment: he copied and messed the code from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551050/how-to-write-prepare-and-execute-statements-in-oop-pdo/42554795#42554795   do u mind explaining why does the code *makes absolutely no sense*  ?